# Getting the date for current day in PHP

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I want to get the date for current day in php. what i tried is here...

```
echo $x."<br>";
echo date("D",$x)."<br>";
```

But the output was

```
21-02-10
Thu
```

It is giving correct date but not the correct day value.Why..?

What I want day is the date for monday for the current week which can be generated on any day of the week. so what I did was, I'm taking the today's day and comparing with (Mon,Tue.... Sun) and respectively creating a timestamp using

```
case "Mon":

$startdate1=date("d-m-y");
$parts = explode('-',$startdate1);
$startdate2 = date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],($parts[0]+1),$parts[2]));
$startdate3 = date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],($parts[0]+2),$parts[2]));
$startdate4 = date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],($parts[0]+3),$parts[2]));
$startdate5 = date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],($parts[0]+4),$parts[2])); 
$startdate6 = date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],($parts[0]+5),$parts[2]));
$startdate7 = date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],($parts[0]+6),$parts[2]));

$dates=array(1 => $startdate1,$startdate2,$startdate3,$startdate4,$startdate5,$startdate6,$startdate7);
$i=1;
while( $i <= 7 )
{
echo $dates[$i];
$i++;
}
break;
```

$date is the final array respective to today that has to be returned. Is there any other better method to do this operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did to resolve it is used the date format ('d-m-Y') instead of ('d-m-y') in date function, which was causing the problem. Hence strtotime accepted the format and gave the correct result for

```
$t=date('d-m-Y');
echo date("D",strtotime($t));
```

Answer (score 35):

I tried this to get current day.

```
echo date('l'); // output: current day.
```

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
//today is monday
if (1 == date('N')){
    $monday = time();
}else{
    $monday = strtotime('last Monday');
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    echo date('d-m-Y', $monday) . '<br>';
    $monday = strtotime('tomorrow', $monday);
}
```

First find Monday, if it is not today, then print 7 dates

Comment: if (1 == date('N')) what is 'N' in this line... can u pls explain me the code a little more...?

Comment: N is the numeric representation for the day of the week. See http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: It really helped me :)

Answer (score 3):

> What I want day is the date for monday
>   for the current week which can be
>   generated on any day of the week.

That's what you want. `$mday` is the month day of this week's Monday. Nevermind if it's not positive, `mktime` will handle that right. `$monday` has the timestamp of the Monday's midnight.

```
$now = getdate();
$mday = $now['mday'] - ($now['wday'] + 6) % 7;
$monday = mktime(0, 0, 0, $now['mon'], $mday, $now['year']);
echo(date('d-m-y', $monday));
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the function date and path to it the "D" that refere to the current day , and it works with me

```
 $today = date("D");
```

and to get the full info about the current date

```
  $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
```

Answer (score 2):

You are likely passing a string as timestamp

```
echo $x."<br>";
echo date("D",$x)."<br>";
```

Remove `$x` and it will output the correct day or change it to

```
$x = '21-02-2010';
echo date('D', strtotime($x));
```

Comment: Still the output is Thu for $x = '21-02-2010';

Answer (score 2):

> what i tried is here...
>
> `echo date("D",$x)."<br>";`

`date` expects a timestamp (int) value as the second parameter. Your `$x` is a string containing an ambiguous date format. Convert that date into a timestamp first, using `strptime` or `strtotime` and use the `date` function correctly to get the correct day value.

Regarding your second part, you don't need to (and shouldn't) check the day name to calculate the correct Monday, Tuesday etc. A more efficient approach is *for example* using `strtotime` to get `last Monday` etc.

Comment: echo date("D",strtotime($x,1))."<br>";
this is also not giving correct answer.